# jquery REGEX matching exact term

Tags: jquery, regex

I am using jQuery and a DataTable with a custom faceted navigation.  I create a pipe delimited list of values of each of the checkboxes to populate the fnFilter for the dataTable.  Uncheck a box and it rebuilds the list without that value.  It works fine except where there are values like 'Engineering' and 'Mechanical Engineering'.  If the 'Engineering' value is checked, but the 'Mechanical Engineering' value is not, 'Mechanical Engineering is not limited out (since the 'Engineering' value meets the criteria for both).  I'm trying to modify the string using REGEX to limit the terms to the string.

Row I   Engineering

Row II  Mechanical Engineering

Row III Engineering, Mechanical Engineering, Electrical Engineering

So by unchecking 'Engineering', Rows II and III would remain, but Row I would filter out.

I have modified this to include more complete code.  I'm not sure how to set up a demo here, but I'd be happy to do that.

```
//dataTable configuration
    $('#directoryTable').dataTable({
                    "sDom": 'lprtpi',
                    "iDisplayLength": 25,
                    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
                    "aaSorting": [[0,'asc'],[1,'asc']],
                    "aoColumns": [
                            {"bSortable": true},
                            {"bSortable": true},
                            {"bSortable": false},
                            {"bSortable": false,"sSortDataType": "dom-checkbox" }
                    ]
    })



    //custom filtering on industry clusters     
    var oTable = $('#directoryTable').dataTable();

    $('input[class="cluster"]').click(function(){
        //get list of values of checked boxes in cluster class
        var checkedList = $('input[class="cluster"]:checked').map(function() {return this.value;}).get().join('|');

        //var checkedList = $('input[class="cluster"]:checked').map(function() {return "^"+this.value+",|^"+ this.value+"$|,"+ this.value+"$|,"+ this.value+",";}).get().join('|');
        window.console&&console.log(checkedList);
        //limit results to selected values
        if ($('input[class="cluster"]').is(":checked")) {

            //uses a REGEX filter with a | delimited (OR) filter, only on the third column
            oTable.fnFilter(checkedList, 2, true,false);
            //window.console&&console.log('clicked ' + $(this).val());

        //clear the filter when unchecked
        } else {
          oTable.fnFilter('',2);
          oTable.fnFilter('');
        }
    });
```

I'm very new at jQuery, and I really appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Can you set up a demo here? I'm having a hard time understand what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if this is off base, but without the full breadth of your code I can't determine if what I have here is valid. I hope it helps.

```
var reg = /^Engineering$/gi;

var a = ['Mechanical Engineering','engineering','Silver Mining','Engineering','Silver and Gold','Electrical Engineering'];

var items = jQuery(a).filter(function(i,v){
    return reg.test(v);
}).get().join('|');

// items returns engineering|Engineering
// I believe your reg, would just be value of the element that is clicked/unclicked.
```

so, if you wanted to pass this dynamically, do something like:

```
//some function to capture the arg/checkbox value
 var val = arg,
     reg = new RegExp('\^' + val + '\$', "gi");
     reg.test(v); // v being the string passed in for your reiteration.
```

Comment: I added additional code above.  Hopefully it is easier to see what I'm doing.  I manually added the REGEX to my fnFilter, bypassing other code which should give me the same result anytime I click any checkbox.  The result I get from the dataTable is that there are no matching records.

oTable.fnFilter("/^Engineering$/gi", 2, true,false);

Comment: ok, updated my original post. Use the new RegExp, that should work for you.